# Metro UI css and js files are changing my page style

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metro-ui-css

I am using live tile in my index page. I imported css and js files from CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
<script href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
```

I have jquery date picker and inputs on my page. If I import files, my inputs and datepicker style has lost.

I want to use only for tiles. What can I do ?

Comment: It means those files from cdn are overriding your inner styles. Did you try to force your inner style with `!important`?

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz Yes, I mean this. I tried.

Comment: I suggest you to use required styles from metro ui. Get your desired styles from browser and use them in your own css files. Probably this is the best way to understand why they are overriding your styles.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz Thanks for answer. I downloaded css and js files  from metro ui site. I only took those parts about tile and then solved :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you needed a part of external file, you can use it like this. Also this method will load your page more quickly than importing all files.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz Yes, you are right ! Thank you again.